# How to redraw text rendered using SVGRenderer in Highcharts React?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am using the SVGRenderer to draw the total value in the center of donut chart shown below:

[image]

The code to do this is shown below (please see CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-demo-4bzh8))

```
export const PieChart = ({ title, totalLabel, pieSize, pieInnerSize, data }: PieChartProps) => {
    const chartRef = useRef(null);
    const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(initialOptions);

    useEffect(() => {
        // set options from props
        setChartOptions({...});

        // compute total
        const total = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.y, 0);

        // render total
        const totalElement = chart.renderer.text(total, 0, 0).add();
        const totalElementBox = totalElement.getBBox();

        // Place total
        totalElement.translate(
            chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth - totalElementBox.width) / 2,
            chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight / 2
        );
        ...
    }, [title, totalLabel, pieSize, pieInnerSize, data]);

    return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            containerProps={{ style: { width: '100%', height: '100%' } }}
            options={chartOptions}
            ref={chartRef}
        />
    );
};
```

However this approach has two issues:

1. When chart is resized, the total stays where it is - so it is no longer centered inside the pie.

[image]

2. When the chart data is changed (using the form), the new total is drawn over the existing one.

[image]

How do I solve these issues? With React, I expect the chart to be fully re-rendered when it is resized or when the props are changed. However, with Highcharts React, the chart seems to keep internal state which is not overwritten with new props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two options for this case:

1. Use the `events.render` callback, destroy and render a new label after each redraw:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ps97bxkg/

2. Use the `events.render` callback to trasnlate those labels after each redraw:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6kwag80z/

Render callback triggers after each chart redraw, so it is fully useful in this case - more information
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks again, @Sebastian. I was able to implement option 1 to fix both issues. CodeSandbox is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I placed items inside of highcharts using their svgrenderer functionality (labels, in particular, but you can also use the text version of svgrenderer), and was able to make them responsive

I was able to do something by manually changing the x value of my svgRenderer label.

I'm in angular and have a listener for screen resizing:

Also Note that you can change the entire SVGRenderer label with the attr.text property.

```
this.chart = Highcharts.chart(.....);
// I used a helper method to create the label
this.chart.myLabel = this.labelCreationHelperMethod(this.chart, data);

this.windowEventService.resize$.subscribe(dimensions => {
  if(dimensions.x < 500) { //this would be your charts resize breakpoint
  // here I was using a specific chart series property to tell where to put my x coordinate,
  // you can traverse through the chart object to find a similar number, 
  // or just use a hardcoded number
   this.chart.myLabel.attr({ y: 15, x: this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 20 }); 
  } else {
   this.chart.myLabel.attr({ y: 100, x: this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 50 });
  }
}

//Returns the label object that we keep a reference to in the chart object.
labelCreationHelperMethod() {
     const y = screen.width > 500 ? 100 : 15; 
     const x = screen.width > 500 ? this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 50 : 
        this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 20


      // your label
      const label = `<div style="color: blue"...> My Label Stuff</div>`
      return chart.renderer.label(label, x, y, 'callout', offset + chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop + 80, true)
  .attr({
    fill: '#e8e8e8',
    padding: 15,
    r: 5,
    zIndex: 6
  })
  .add();
 }
```